# Can't get my Javascript to add or remove class

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a simple quiz that asks users what kind of car they should buy. I can't get the quiz to show one question at a time like I want it to. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The full code is on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Eyad-Alshafi/pen/YVZYBe)

I'm sure the problem is this part of the code though. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
//question counter
var question = 1;
maxQuestions = 4;

//event handler for click event
var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
nextButton.onClick = function() {
  question++;
  if (question === maxQuestions) {
    //hide the next button
    $(nextButton).addClass("hidden");
  }
  //hide the last question  
  $('question' + (question - 1)).addClass("hidden");
  //show the current question  
  $('question' + question).removeClass("hidden");  
};

var prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');
prevButton.onClick = function() {
  question--;
  if (question === 1) {
    //hide the prev button
    $(prevButton).addClass("hidden");
  }
  //hide current question
  $('question' + (question + 1)).addClass("hidden");
  //show the last question
  $('question' + question).removeClass("hidden");
};

//show submit
if (question === maxQuestions) {
  $('submit').removeClass("hidden");
};
```

Comment: You seem to want to select by ID so your selector should be  `$('#question' + question)`

Comment: Are you using jQuery or PrototypeJS? Given that the strings you're passing `$()` are not CSS selectors, I'd say PrototypeJS, but...

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo. The property name is `onclick` not `onClick`

Comment: Re my question above: I could probably tell if I went over to CodePen, but the full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Hello it looks like there are 2 things that need to get updated

1. Added '#' to your element selector
2. using onclick instead of onClick

here is a link to the update in codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmpQxo

```
//question counter
var question = 1;
maxQuestions = 4;

//event handler for click event
var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
nextButton.onclick = function() {
  question++;
  if (question === maxQuestions) {
    //hide the next button
    $(nextButton).addClass("hidden");
  }
  console.log('next', question);
  //hide the last question  
  $('#question' + (question - 1)).addClass("hidden");
  //show the current question  
  $('#question' + question).removeClass("hidden");  
};

var prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');
prevButton.onclick = function() {
  question--;
  if (question === 1) {
    //hide the prev button
    $(prevButton).addClass("hidden");
  }
  //hide current question
  $('#question' + (question + 1)).addClass("hidden");
  //show the last question
  $('#question' + question).removeClass("hidden");
};

//show submit
if (question === maxQuestions) {
  $('#submit').removeClass("hidden");
};
```

Comment: I used mrdeleon's answer but I'm still having trouble. The next button work fine now, but the previous and submit buttons never show.  https://codepen.io/Eyad-Alshafi/pen/YVZYBe

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery already, so you don't necessarily have to keep track of the questions with indexes. jQuery provides `.siblings()`, `.next()`, and `.prev()` to help navigate.

For example a quick solution that uses those instead of indices could look like this

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmWXeQ?editors=1111